# How to use CSS to increase the contrast on visited hyperlinks?

Tags: css, accessibility

I am using a browser custom-CSS for changing the color visited hyperlinks to magenta, just to be able to see what I clicked or not.

The problem is that in some cases the contrast is too bad for this and I do want to add some kind of glowing around the text from the CSS, just to be able to improve the contrast.

I tried to follow some guides I found online for adding this but I seen no effect on my test pages.

```
text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px red !important;
```

Note: I tried this only on Safari and Chrome (OS X).

Comment: Have you tried .hyperlink:visited { ... } ?

Comment: That's the right property, can you add the rest of your css and html or post an example so we can be sure its being set properly?

Comment: It works fine in my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TheNix/MU3me/

Comment: @Nix I tried you code in Safari, Chrome and Firefox no effect, and the fiddle seems to work if I change other fields, like background-color. I also checked not to have other extensions installed in the browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research, I've found out that this is actually intended behaviour, due to privacy limitations. You may style:

- Color
- Background-color
- Border-color
- Outline color

Here's an article on the subject: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector